# No such device when airodump-ng mon0

Tags: aircrack-ng

Problem with aircrack.When i start mon0 it says not such device

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Then it gives a bunch of processes and say at the bottom:

```
wlan0        Unknown        wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags :no such device

                            (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

When try to sniff and run:`airodump-ng mon0`
,it says :

```
Interface mon0:
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
```

please help